# Missing characters when assigning strings to a structure

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct person
{
    char *lastName;
    char *firstName;
    char *Initiales;
    char *Mobile;
    char *Classe;
    int initialSort;
    float randomSort;

}person;

int main()
{
person *persons = setPersons(30);
}


person *setPersons(int length)
{
    person *persons = malloc(length*sizeof(struct person));

    FILE *file = fopen("persons.txt","r");
    char *buffer=malloc(100*sizeof(char)); char **strTab;
    fgets(buffer, 100, file);
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        fgets(buffer, 100, file);
        strTab=splitStr(buffer);
        printf("%s,%s\n",strTab[0],strTab[1]);
        persons[i]=setPerson(strTab);
        printf("%s,%s\n",persons[0].lastName,persons[0].firstName);
    }

    return persons;
}

person setPerson(char **str)
{
    person p;
    p.lastName = str[0];
    p.firstName = str[1];
    p.Initiales = str[2];
    p.Mobile = str[3];
    p.Classe = str[4];
    p.InitialSort = atof(str[5]);
    p.RandomSort = atoi(str[6]);

    return p;
}

char **splitStr(char *str){
    char **strTab = malloc(30* sizeof(char*));
    char *token;
    int i=0;

    token = strtok(str, ";");
    while (token!=NULL){
        strTab[i++]=token;
        token = strtok(NULL, ";");
    }
    return strTab;
}
```

Here I'm reading every line of a file, lines contains strings(name,number,etc) separated by ";", i split each line and affect each string to a structure member.

So if I run this, first print in setPersons() is gonna show Conde,Mamy and second printf (after I affect the result of setPerson to persons[i])  is going to show Conde,y, same for almost every structure in the array of structures.

Comment: you have only a structure not a list. You must to implement a list each node have a `Person`

Comment: Just as a side note: Calling `malloc` without calling `free` causes a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). and should not be done. However, this is not related to the problem you are having.

Comment: In the second printf, you always print `persons[0].lastName` and `persons[0].firstName`. Is this intentional or did you want to print `persons[i].lastName` and `persons[i].firstName` instead? Is my assumption correct that this is intentional, because you want to see if the first person gets corrupted by processing more persons?

Comment: It was just for test purpose, the problem was in my split function as Andersk mentionned, it's working now :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your `split` function.

You first allocate an array of char pointers, fair enough but you cannot use what is returned from `strtok` since it modifies the original string it is passed by each call to `strtok(NULL, ";")`. Instead you need to copy the returned value to a new buffer before calling `strtok` again

e.g.

```
char **splitStr(char *str){
    char **strTab = malloc(30* sizeof(char*));
    char *token;
    int i=0;

    token = strtok(str, ";");
    while (token!=NULL){
        strTab[i++]=strdup(token); // <--- malloc/strcpy
        token = strtok(NULL, ";");
    }
    return strTab;
}
```

Also don't forget to free your malloced memory when you are done with it.

I would suggest you set `strTab[i] = NULL` as the last thing you do in the function as well, that way you can easily go through the array knowing when there are no more entries.

```
for(int i = 0; strTab[i] != NULL; ++i) { ... }
```

Comment: Please note that `strdup` is not part of the official C standard. If you want to be sure that your code is portable, you must use `malloc` and `strcpy` instead.

Comment: as noted in my comment after strdup